# Crashlytics ... stuck with only one app in my organization

Tags: android, crashlytics

I installed Crashlytics in my ADT-Eclipse IDE, and used added my first app Swimmer ( package name com.swimtechtest.swimmer ) in my organization swimtech

I am trying now to add another project  swimmer-Log  ( package name com.swimtechtest.swimmerlog) into the SAME organization...  so I started the Crashlytics plugin in Eclipse , got a list of my projects and selected the new project .. hit next

but then a got a list of organization to choose, some duplicated with 0 apps , other with 4 apps... ( see image attached .. ) I don't understand where all that stuff is coming from neither how to clean it....

selecting the first in the list ( with 4 apps ) I get then the changes to be done im the Manifest.xml, with an API key... then hitting next , I'm asked to build and run...

running the app :
- I get an error in the console, cannot access the settings for this project com.swimtechtest.swimmerlog
- when I go to my crashlytics account , I can still see my first project ... but not the new one added into my organization

to be short .. it's a big mess, seem not so easy to manage multiple projects , how do I clean the situation now ?

[image: select organization in Crashlytics plugin]